# Cutting a JsonStr

Tags: java, android

my code looks like this:

```
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);



        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                // Getting JSON Array node
                contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS);
```

....

so i want to get Data from a Json Obj. My ap fails on the "try" part because it tells me that

".../b> on line **3370**
{"bpactivities":[{"id":"160", ...... "

so i assume its because of tags like /b>

What i want to do now is to cut everything in the jsonStr until " {"bpactivities": .. " starts.

so for example the string is now " i dont want this stuff to be here {"bpactivities": ..,, "  " but i want it like this: "{"bpactivities": .. " "

so how can i cut everything before my actual jsonObj starts? Is there a way?

thx in advance

Comment: Please post the JSON string you're parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know how the part before your jsonObj starts you can go with:

```
    String jsonStr = " i dont want this stuff to be here {\"bpactivities\": ..,, \" ";

    System.out.println(jsonStr.split(" here ")[1]);
    //returns_ {"bpactivities": ..,, "
```

String.split(String regex) returns a String-Array. In this case the first element contains the part before the regex, the second element the last part.

Your solution with:

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr.substring(jsonStr.indexOf('{')));
```

works as well, but if there is any '{' before your actual jsonObj it will cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

ok i solved it like this:

JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr.substring(jsonStr.indexOf('{')));